# Unresolved reference: editText

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm not able to use elements of xml file like text view, image view in my kotlin file since I have to make intents.
Unresolved reference: editText

```
val name = editText.editableText.toString()
```

here editText is not acting as previously used, I expected this to be having a reference with xml file's text view element editText.

Comment: For a variable to work you must have to defined it in proper scope . in case you are trying to make use of kotlin Synthetic then don't because its deprecated now . Use `ViewBinding` instead . https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the reference to your `EditText`. The classical way to get it is by doing something like that:

```
val editText = findViewById(R.id.editText)
```

The id refers to the `android:id` attribute you gave it in the XML layout.

However, you might also look into other ways to get this reference. E.g. [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).